# If statement check if string is a question mark

Tags: php, if-statement

I have been programming in PHP since almost 15 years, and today I am asking a simple question that is puzzeling me.  I need to check if the string is a "?"... but it does not work.

```
$niveau = 0;
$result = "Original";
if($niveau == "?") $result = "Found a question";
echo "Result :".$result;
```

Output:
**Result : Found a question**

Question, since the value of `$niveau` is `0`, the if statement should not change the value of `$retour`, but it DOES! Why? Can somebody explain this behaviour?

Comment: I get `Original`. See this: [OnlinePHPFunctions SandBox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/82ff499e63a3939ce1add73bd63eeff33ab2d345)

Comment: In PHP 8 it doesn't. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php for 7 you can use the type check as well (`$niveau === "?"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of [Backward Incompatible Changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php), which works fine in PHP 8, but not in PHP Version < 8. The problem here is you're comparing string with a number, where it might go wrong.

```js
0 == "foo" // True (PHP < 8) / False (PHP 8)
```

It is because, the integral value of any string is `0`:

```php
<?php
  echo intval("Hello"); // 0
  echo intval("?");     // 0
```

And comparison with `0` gives `true`.

So convert `$niveau` to string and then compare for backward compatibility.

```php
<?php
  $niveau = 0;
  $result = "Original";
  if ($niveau . "" == "?") {
    $result = "Found a question";
  }
  echo "Result :".$result;
```

This gives me:

```
Result :Original
```

[Check here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a44f0bc1e873313c9400173c0345a50f460f4e5) on all the versions!

Alternate way, use strict check with three `===`:

```php
if ($niveau === "?")
```

Comment: Love your answer, since it make sence to create a text variable from a 'maybe' int variable.  Thank... I will sleep better tonight. :-)

Comment: @ClaudeDeslandes You're welcome! Thanks you!  Made your question a lot better and cleaner too.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare the same type variable. When has different type, the result may is not what you're expected.

```
"0" == "?" // is false
0 == "?"   // is true (PHP 7.3)
```

When compare a string with int, the string will be take as a int.

```
intval("?") // which is 0 (PHP 7.3)
```

so `0 == 0` will return true;

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  Claude :-)